# Computing the Exceptional inverse image functor for some simple closed immersions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves, derived-categories

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism between schemes. Then, under mild hypothesis on $f, X$ and $Y$, we have *Grothendieck duality*. This gives an isomorphism

$\mathcal{R}\mathcal{H}om_{Y}(\mathcal{R}f_{x}\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}) \cong 
\mathcal{R}f_{x}\mathcal{R}\mathcal{H}om_{X}(\mathcal{F},f^{!}\mathcal{G})$.

Here, $\mathcal{R}f_{x}: D^{b}(Qcoh(X)) \rightarrow D^{b}(Qcoh(Y))$ is the right derived functor of push forward (sorry, the latex is being a bit funny, hence the unusual notation), and $f^{!}: D^{b}(Qcoh(Y)) \rightarrow D^{b}(Qcoh(X))$ is the right adjoint of the right derived push forward, as given by Grothendieck duality. People usually call $f^{!}$ the *Exceptional inverse image functor*.

My question is that I would like to compute $f^{!}$ for some simple closed immersions.

More specifically, consider the following closed immersions, given by the canonical embeddings:

$i : \mathbb{A}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$

$i : \mathbb{P}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$

$i : Gr^{k,n} \rightarrow Gr^{k,n+1}$.

What are

$i^{!}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}})$,

$i^{!}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n+1}})$,

$i^{!}(\mathcal{O}_{Gr^{k,n+1}})$ ?

The stacks project gives an explicit description on how to compute the Exceptional inverse image functor in the case of closed immersions, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A74.

The problem is that I don't know how to `compute' with this explicit description, and I feel as if, for the maps I have described above, one should be able to say something explicit!

I am not an Algebraic Geometer by training, so if someone could take my hand and walk me through the technicalities, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am on my phone now and can't type up an answer, so I'll leave a suggestion: using Serre duality, you can show that for $i: X\to Y$ a proper morphism between smooth proper varieties $i^!F=i^*F\otimes\omega_X\otimes i^*\omega_Y^{-1}[x-y]$, where $x,y$ are the dimensions of $X,  Y$.

Comment: This should settle the question, except for the case of affine spaces. But then everything is affine, you can switch to the language of modules so the description from the stacks project should stop being mysterious in this case too. Hope this helps.